# iOS animation: Slide a large UiImageView from Behind a small UIImageView

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I am struggling to properly describe this problem but basically I have a an imageView which is 200 px wide and 40 px high... On a button click I need to slide another imageView underneath and behind the smaller imageView to make it appear as if the small imageView is the 'top'. I have mocked up a basic image below...

I am familiar with the animation code blocks however my question is... I dont want the largeImageView to display above the smallImageView... I only want it to display underneath the smallImageView once the animation block begins...

[image: Half animation]

[image: Full Animation]

EDIT: Current Animation Block:

ViewDidLoad:

```
//Place small imageView offScreen and hide LargeImageView
_smallImageView.frame = CGRectMake(273, 131, 240, 43);
_LargeImageDropDownView.frame = CGRectMake(45, 131, 229, 43);
_LargeImageDropDownView.hidden = YES;
```

Then onClick of the button it does:

```
-(void)animation
{
//First Animate SmallView to the Left
[UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{

    _smallImageView.frame = CGRectMake(40, 131, 240, 215);

}completion:^(BOOL finished)
 {
     //Then unhide large view and animate it down
     _LargeImageDropDownView.hidden = NO;
     [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{

         _LargeImageDropDownView.frame = CGRectMake(45, 84, 229, 215);

     }completion:^(BOOL finished)
      {
          //completed
      }];
 }];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like that Smaller ImageView should come in the front.

By setting that view as :

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.smallerImageView];
```

Comment: Thanks for that... It works in terms of bringing the SmallerImageView. The problem is more though that when the largeImageView is behind the small one it is still visible above the smallView.. I will update the question with an image thats a bit more clear..

Comment: I'm confused , If you initialise the LargeImageView from the small ImageView . Then it shouldn't happen na?

Comment: How do you mean initialise the LargeImageView from the small ImageView?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time too look at thie by the way Kumar, much appreciated.

Comment: _LargeImageDropDownView.frame = CGRectMake(45, 84, 229, 215); change this according to the smaller View.

Comment: Ahh I see what you mean... I was running into the problem when the subViews inside the largeView would not animate with the largeView but  it was simply because I missed the clipSubView option...